# How to use Microsoft KMS server 2016 to activate a Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, licensing, windows-server-2016, kms

We are busy building a new environment. Most of our servers are Windows server 2016. And so is our KMS server.

To run some old applications, we need to activate a few Windows Server 2008 R2 operating systems (Via Citrix PVS).

When I add the Windows Server 2008 R2 KMS key to the Windows Server 2016 KMS server I get this error message;

> Error: 0xC004F050 The Software Licensing Service reported that the product key is invalid.

We successfully added Windows Server 2016 KMS keys to the KMS server

Questions;

1. Is it possible to activate Windows Server 2008 via a 2016 KMS server
2. Why is our product key failing?

Comment: JFL has answered Q1. For Q2, add corresponding output of `slmgr /dlv` of both KMS host & client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows Server KMS key allow to to activate any older version of Windows Server.

So, since you added Windows Server 2016 KMS keys to the KMS server, you have nothing special to do, your Windows Server 2008 should active just fine, provide you reached the activation threshold (5 servers IIRC).

Note : this is not true for Office.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up JFL. But my server 2008 does not get activated. I've read about the 5 server threshold, and that they need to be non-virtual servers. There is no way I can get that done, is there anyway to overcome this threshold?

Comment: I'm not aware that the servers need to be non-virtual. We have a fully virtualized network, without any physical windows and KMS works fine, but we don't use Hyper-V.. Temporary creating a virtual server  in any hypervisor 5 time should do the trick. The 5 servers don't need to run concurently, they just have to make an activation request to the KMS server once (you could even use VirtualBox for this)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'm gonna try that and get back here.